# Comment javascript methods in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, comments

Is there a way to insert a snippet for XML comments in javascript in Visual Studio 2010 with automatically generated parameters?

If I type `///` here...

```
function foo(a, b){
```

...it should change to this (depending on the parameters):

```
function foo(a, b){
    /// <summary>$cursorhere</summary>
    /// <param name="a" type="string">Param a</param>
    /// <param name="b" type="string">Param b</param>
    /// <returns type="function">Return function</returns>
```

So it would be similar to the snippet generation if I'm in C# code.

***EDIT***

To clarify, I just want to know if there is a shortcut or existing plugin to achieve the functionality mentioned above *approximately*.

Comment: How do you expect it to know that `a` and `b` are strings? Also, how can you tell what it returns?

Comment: Yep, I don't know that, thats right. But I would use these parameters as default. And VS could determine the object types by existing function calls in the project, but thats just an idea. The main thing I want to achieve is to just type some letters and the summary gets created (with the amount of parameters).

Comment: There is a way I'm sure, Visual Studio 2010 supports plugins, what have you tried? Have you looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx?

Comment: _"And VS could determine the object types by existing function calls in the project"_ - Or possibly it could _guess,_ since the same function could be called with different types...

Comment: He guys, thanks for your time, I was just looking for a easy way to add javascript comments similar to C# comments, I don't want to write an own *plugin* for that and of course it has to *guess* the variable type if there is more then one function call, but that is not necessary at all. And what have I tried? Just googling, couldn't find anything. I hoped to get an answer here like "just press A, B then C" or "it's not possible".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can make a code snippet, but that seems too much trouble to me. I use [JScript vsdoc Stub Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e122a031-d748-41e9-87b1-7b56d8610d8b), it generates XML comments like these ones:

[image]

> This extension's goal is to provide a simple way to add vsdocs to JavaScript that acts similar to other XML comments provided by Visual Studio. A comment stub is created when a triple-slash ("///") is added on a new line.

Comment: VS 2012 version is also available [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e122a031-d748-41e9-87b1-7b56d8610d8b).

Comment: the 2012 version is here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cb7304b-ad78-4283-ba2b-42804657fcdd

Comment: The latter version (for VS2012,VS2013, VS2014) only works with  `Visual Studio Pro` _not_ `Visual Studio Express` :(

Comment: @DimitryK have you tried Visual Studio Community? I haven't verified that it works, but it's worth a shot: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx

Comment: @WetNoodles, with access to extensions, `Typescript` and `Apache Cordoba` support it looks promising. Will try tonight.

Comment: @DimitryK okay yes, I just confirmed that this works. Community is essentially the next version of Express.

Comment: Just found that if I have file `program.js` and I want to have Intellisense for the `my-library.js` when I use, it. I need to add `/// <reference path="/js/path-to-lib/my-library.js" />` to the top of `program.js`

Comment: The 2017 version is here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MichaelObermeyer.DocStubsJs2017

Comment: @Evandor Thank you very much. I was searching exactly this thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for JS intellisense comments and references, described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx

Basically it's very similar to what you expected.

UPDATE: sorry, didn't read your question properly.  Snippets are trivial to make for yourself, it's not even a plugin really, just an xml file you add to your file system.  You can use the snippet editor: http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/  to make it even easier.