# Is it possible to generate comments for TypeScript methods/classes in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Is there a way to generate JSDoc comments in Visual Studio like XML comments in C#? I.g. by typing ///? There is a plugin for JavaScript. Is there something simular for TypeScript, yet?

Comment: Thanks, but not what I am looking for. I don't want to keep my comments in JS. I want to generate them by typing /// or /** above my function or class stub.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489353/comment-javascript-methods-in-visual-studio

Comment: @YvesR this is about JavaScript. I am looking for TypeScript. No duplicate. I know about the plugin to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There isn't anything for TypeScript yet.

You could request it as a feature either from the TypeScript Visual Studio extension, Web Essentials or write a Visual Studio extension and stick it in the library.

Comment: was that changed in version 0.9?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated my extension to support JSDoc and VSDoc in both JavaScript and TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012+.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cb7304b-ad78-4283-ba2b-42804657fcdd?SRC=VSIDE

> DocStubsJs [Formerly known as JavaScript vsdoc Generator]
>
> This extension's goal is to provide a simple way to add documentation
>   to JavaScript and TypeScript by adding comment stubs after typing in
>   the opening of a new documentation comment.

To make this seem like less of a shameless plug, Atomineer also supports this, though it's a paid extension (it does a lot more than just a simple stub, though)

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7912CCF4-60B8-4132-BACE-5ACACEB7233B