# Visual Studio - intellisense for javascript custom object

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense

I created the following javascript object:

```
var Content = Content || {};

// Constructor defines properties and inits object
Content.ProductManager = function () {
    // ...
};


Content.ProductManager.prototype = function () {

    // 
    // private members
    // 


    var setProductAsPreviewed = function (args) {
        // code omitted for brevity
        // ....
    };


    //
    // public members
    // 

    return {
        setProductAsPreviewed: setProductAsPreviewed
    };

} ();
```

The object passed to `setProductAsPreviewed` has the following properties:

```
args = {
    productId: int,
    productName: string,
    updateDate: date,
    saveItems: bool
};
```

I want to include XML comments so I can get intellisense for the argument passed to function `setProductAsPreviewed`:

```
var productManager = new window.Content.ProductManager();
// show intellisense when typing the following:
productManager.setProductAsPreviewed(
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489353/comment-javascript-methods-in-visual-studio) shows how to do it for simple args (`string`, `int`, ...), but how to do it for a complex object? I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Is your `args` object generated on the fly, or is there a custom function that defines the type?

Comment: They are generated on the fly, when I invoke the function `productManager.setProductAsPreviewed`. Would it be a good idea to define an object with the desired properties first in order to have intellisense? I was trying to avoid that, because this is the only place where I'll use this object.

Comment: Changed my comment to an answer. I may be wrong though as most of my knowledge of JS intellisense comes from VS2012 so I'd give it a while for other people to have a think =]

Comment: Just had a quick look around and done some googling and can't find anything anywhere near helpful in this regard, even the MSDN docs are pretty bad for this, although it does look like they only support inline documentation for functions as they only mention `<param>`, `<field>` and `<returns>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 21):

As far as I know, you can't tell IntelliSense what fields and methods are on a generic variable if it is being used as a parameter.

If the variable was an array, you could define it like this:

```
function funcWithArrayArg(arrayArg) {
    /// <param name="arrayArg" type="Array" elementType="Number">An array of numbers</param>
}
```

In VS2012 you can annotate objects as well, like so (you can annotate fields on functions used as object constructors, as I demonstrate below but the docs say nothing about anonymous objects like this):

```
var args = {
    /// <field type="Number">Product ID</field>
    productID: int
};
```

Neither of these approaches really do what you want, as the second approach wouldn't give you intellisense on the function argument and you're using VS2010 anyway.

I think your best bet is to define a custom object to be used as an argument object just for that function, after all this is how you would do it in other languages if you wanted to create a custom object as a parameter with intellisense. It might look something like this:

```
function ProductPreviewArgs(productId, productName, updateDate, saveItems) {
    /// <summary>Creates an object for use as the sole argument to the setProductAsPreviewed function</summary>
    /// <param name="productId" type="Number" optional="false">The Product ID</param>
    /// <param name="productName" type="String" optional="false">The Product Name</param>
    /// <param name="updateDate" type="Date" optional="false">The date the product was last updated</param>
    /// <param name="saveItems" type="Boolean" optional="false">Specifies whether or not to save the items</param>
    /// <returns type="ProductPreviewArgs">An object intended for use as the sole argument to the setProductAsPreviewed function</returns>
    /// <field name="productId" type="Number">The Product ID</field>
    /// <field name="productName" type="String">The Product Name</field>
    /// <field name="updateDate" type="Date">The date the product was last updated</field>
    /// <field name="saveItems" type="Boolean">Specifies whether or not to save the items</field>
    this.productId = productId;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
    this.saveItems = saveItems;
}
```

You would get intellisense on the object (which will show what you have put in the `returns` element) here:

```
setProductAsPreviewed(
```

If you then decide to create a new object, you would get IntelliSense here (which will show you the descriptions for each parameter one by one as you add them):

```
setProductAsPreviewed(new ProductPreviewArgs(
```

I'm not entirely sure whether the `type` attribute on the `returns` element will actually work like that, it does in VS2012 and as you might have come to expect by now, the docs are annoyingly bare on this subject; and I don't have a copy of VS2010 to test any of this on right now.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Sean, but this doesn't help. I have a custom object with public functions, I need intellisense for them. Also, I don't want to change the signature of the functions, I want to keep a single argument object.

Comment: Didn't know about that you could specify a parameter/return of an array of a specific type - Intellisense is brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

You can create a separate IntelliSense file, that looks something like this

```
intellisense.annotate(Content, {
  'setProductAsPreviewed ': function() {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>Summary<summary>
    ///   <param name="args" type="ComplexObject">some text here
    /// </signature>
   }
})
```

I believe this should work with some modification